# Handling Optional field search in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm using ES 5.5 and having a query dsl with javasript API request like this

```
client.search({
  index: 'demo',
  type: 'sample',
  body: {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "CityName": {
                query: req.params.city,
                slop: 100
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "StateName": {
                query: req.params.state,
                slop: 100
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "Code": {
                  query: req.params.code,
                  slop: 100
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

This query works fine when user gives all three values.But In my case these three parameters are not mandatory.Either user can give one value or more than one value and given fields `must match` the documents.Searching with one or two values doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the `must` with `should`. refer [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) for more details

```
client.search({
  index: 'demo',
  type: 'sample',
  body: {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [ --> replace this `must` with `should`
          {
            "match": {
              "CityName": {
                query: req.params.city,
                slop: 100
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "StateName": {
                query: req.params.state,
                slop: 100
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "Code": {
                  query: req.params.code,
                  slop: 100
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Thankyou for your quick response.Sorry I missed mentioning that the given field should perform AND operation but the three fields are not mandatory

Comment: Also I dont get how to handle the empty field search which is major problem in my case. Please give me some suggestions to solve this.

Comment: @YazhiniRavi thanks for your comment but these are now new requirements and would advise you to mark upvote and accept and ask a followup question with all the details and I would look into it, also dont forget to add your mapping, example documents and expected documents in your search so that I can easily reproduce it and provide the working solution as you expect.

Comment: Sure @Prerna Gupta.I am having three fields in my UI to query for.Those three fields are optional.Either the user can query one or two or all of them together.But the given fields should perform AND operation search between them and produce me a result.

Comment: @YazhiniRavi ok got it, looks much better, can you please ask this as a followup question and do as suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: And my mapping is quite simple didn't include any complex things.For Example If I have field1,field2,field3 and if I request for field1 and field2 then field3 null request should be handled and field1 and field2 should perform AND operation and return me result.

Comment: @YazhiniRavi got it, I am trying this and will keep you posted also your question was not having the proper tag and I added them so that it reaches to wider audience, can you approve my edit as well